# OpenDkim - PHPMailer - Failure OpenDkim

Tags: postfix, dkim, opendkim

my dkim configuration was working just fine. Im working with an email marketing app, pretty simple, normally i used to send the campaign with a Sender ID that is my domain company, and for the From Email, the customer email. I signed the dkim wih my sender id and my domain company and everything was working just fine but for some reason now im getting dkim failure, idk if anything changed on PHPMailer or in Gmail rules:

Maillog message from my smtp Postfix server

```
Jul 15 10:24:34 companydomain opendkim[183343]: 286315A1BCF: no signing table match for 'info@university.edu.ve'
Jul 15 10:24:34 companydomain opendkim[183343]: 286315A1BCF: key retrieval failed (s=dkim, d=companydomain.com): 'dkim._domainkey.companydomain.com' query failed
```

Gmail Original Text

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; d=companydomain.com; s=dkim; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; t=1689431315; c=relaxed/simple; h=Date:To:From:Reply-To:Subject:Message-ID:X-Mailer:MIME-Version:Content-Type; i=team@mycompanidomain.com; z=Date:Sat,=2015=20Jul=202023=2010:28:35=20-0400 |To:user@gmail.com |From:=3D?UTF-8?Q?Instituto_Pedag=3DC3=3DB3gico_de_Caracas?=3D=20<info@customerdomain.edu.ve> |Reply-To:user@gmail.com |Subject:Bienvenido=20Cliente |Message-ID:<MyZhklUNeLD68Ba0maXIEDVYBtTGcBKu0tCwv4NEyPU@companydomain.com> |X-Mailer:PHPMailer=206.8.0=20(https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) |MIME-Version:1.0 |Content-Type:multipart/alternative=3B=20boundary=3D"b1=3D_MyZhklUNeLD68Ba 0maXIEDVYBtTGcBKu0tCwv4NEyPU"; bh=oyle56yHSYBUkyZZ/Zuf0g/9jNuIcgHbPw9t44NuqaI=; b=hJzqH6LJfmUkHffAdUc/qUgwHiDNLSPk6tD916gleLGKAN96s2iPrTPvqNIZaAd1/jw30xu5D eRX2/J22Sq3cdFky3r2l2uVQeWNdfZMYWzrTcd4pFOz04mjMrVQsDl0wynr7I6a+tGCOXfZvo q+O7IRmkyry4ocOciaw/etKp0=
```

This is my code but like a said, in the code and server nothing changed, and everyhing was wokring just perfect:

I check that all content was all good.

```
$this->mail->DKIM_domain = $domainId;
$this->mail->DKIM_private = __DIR__ . "/../assets/smtp/" . $domainId;
$this->mail->DKIM_selector = 'dkim';
$this->mail->DKIM_passphrase = '';
$this->mail->DKIM_identity = $sender;
```

Comment: Please add your OpenDKIM configuration and the signing tables.

Comment: I just found the error, for some reason my selector changed to 'defualt' dont know the reason

Comment: Someone edited a configuration file. :)

Comment: please share the output of your answer as an answer, else we will be remembered that we have to solve the Case

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the selector changed to `default`. How could I know it? just chekcing the file `/etc/opendkim.conf`

```
##  Defines the name of the selector to be used when signing messages.
Selector        default
```

So I changed the next line

```
$this->mail->DKIM_selector = 'dkim';
```

to

```
$this->mail->DKIM_selector = 'default';
```